# JQuery object object output

Tags: jquery, onclick

this  is my table button with value

```
'<tr>
   <td>' + valueAusData.Spieler_Name + '</td>
   <td>' +  valueAusData.Note + '</td>
   <td>' + valueAusData.Tore +'</td>
   <td> <button class="edit-modal btn btn-info" id="inputSpieler" value="valueAusData.Tore">' + "Edit" + '</button>
</tr>';
```

and here is my java script function

```
 $( '#myTable' ).on( 'click', 'button', function(g) {
        alert(g);
 });
```

But I get back object object and not the value of valueAusData?

Okay I have the solution

```
alert($(this).val());
```

But how can I store more the 1 field in the button value part?
I need value="valueAusData.Tore" and value="valueAusData.Note" and then I want to alert them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), `function(g)` is :

> handler
>   Type: Function( Event eventObject [, Anything extraParameter ] [, ... ] )

So `g` is an `Event` which is an `Object`.

I think that you are trying to display a `modal`, so add this line instead of `alert(g);` :

```
$("#myModalId").modal('show');
```

Answer (score 0):

If ausData is type object, when you try to convert it to a string, result will be Object object. If you expect to get the entire object as a string use `JSON.stringify(data)`